Unable to Verify Successful Login After Google Authentication using Passportjs in React.js and Node.js on Hosted Version (Works Fine Locally)
Description
I've encountered an issue with my application's Google OAuth2 authentication flow. The authentication process works flawlessly on my local system, but when I host the application and attempt to authenticate, it fails. Here's a breakdown of the problem and the steps I've taken:
Problem
After successful authentication, the server redirects properly, but when trying to verify authentication with a /login/success route, it fails.
Error Received
I'm receiving an Axios "Network Error" when attempting to access the /login/success route from the frontend. The error message suggests a network issue, but I'm unsure why it's happening.
Backend Code (Node.js with Passport.js)
app.get("/login/sucess", async (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    res.status(200).json({ message: "user is logged in", user: req.user });
  } else {
    res.status(400).json({ message: "Not Authorized" });
  }
});

Frontend Request for verification of login:
const getUser = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      "https://loginwithgooglemern.onrender.com/login/sucess",
      { withCredentials: true }
    );
    setUserdata(response.data.user);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
  }
};


Additional Details:

I've configured CORS in my backend to allow requests from my frontend domain.
Redirect URIs in the Google Developer Console are configured correctly.img from googlewebconsole
Cookies seem to be set properly after authentication (confirmed via browser's developer tools).
Here's the link to the hosted application for testing.
GitHub repository for reference: GitHub Repository Link


Everything is working very fine on the local system but when i try to host it and then try to authenticate, the authentication part also works and the server successfully redirects but then comes the problem...i have written a "/login/success" route to verify if the user has successfully authenticated or not.
I Expect the application to work fine on the hosted version but what i think is that somehow, the cookies are not being sent properly on the hosted version because i dont find any other reason for the "/login/success" route to not return true for the logged in user...
Also here are the cookies for the site after the authenticating the user:
screenshot of the cookies for the website
I have added all the required information...i am stuck at this issue for last 15 days, any help would be really appreciated... Thankyou

In your backend/app.js as observed in your Github Repo
Your are not configuring a cookie
app.use(session({
secret: process.env.ANURAG,
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: true}));

cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true, // Set to true if using HTTPS
    sameSite: 'lax', // Or 'none' if using cross-site cookies with secure: true
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // duration of cookie validity
  }    

Further you can store sessions in a db
store: MongoStore.create({
    mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_URL,
    collectionName: 'sessions'
  })

